# JavaFX bind a hyperlink to a label

Tags: java, javafx

I am using MVP in my JavaFX application.

Resources:

```
public class InfoStageResources{

     StringProperty lblBlogText;
     Hyperlink linkBlog;

     InfoStageResources() {
         this.lblBlogText = new SimpleStringProperty("link");
         this.linkBlog = new Hyperlink("link");
     }

}
```

Controller:

```
public class InfoStageController{
     private InfoStageView view;
     private InfoStageResources res;

     public void initView(){
          this.res = new InfoStageResources();
          this.view = new InfoStageView(this.res);

          this.initViewBindings();
     }

     private void initViewBindings(){
          this.view.lblBlog.textProperty().bind(this.res.lblBlogText);
          //this will not work
          this.view.lblBlog.textProperty().bind(this.res.linkBlog);
     }
}
```

View

In my InfoStageView in just init my labels and style my view.

How can bind my Hyperlink to my label. I tried some things but without success.
My StringProperty `lblBlogText` isn't clickable but easy to bind.

My goal: I want to open the browser with the link.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24450989/6077352

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
 this.view.lblBlog.textProperty().bind(this.res.linkBlog.textProperty());
```

Comment: yes I found this too but then in my GUI is only a "text" and not a clickable hyperlink --> now I replaced my label with a Hyperlink and it works :)