# JAVAFX: Get User input using dialog before starting main application window

Tags: javafx

I have a client application, and I want to get the server address, port, and some other info from the user in order to initialize the controller of the main stage.
Currently my code look like this

```
public class MemoryGameClient extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage mainStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader fxml = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MemoryGameClient.fxml"));
        MemoryGameClientController controller = fxml.getController()
        Parent root = loader.load();
        controller.connect(SERVER_ADDRESS, PORT, GAME_BOARD_SIZE);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        mainStage.setScene(scene);
        mainStage.show()
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

It works fine using the hardcoded values, but I want to be able to open a DialogPane or something like that to get those values from user before initializing the `scene` and running the main application logic.

Can I set an empty `Scene` that launch a dialog and after that quitting and starting the main stage? Can I do that from the controller before `mainStage.show()`?

(I need the user input not only for connecting the server but also to determine the size of the `GridPane` in `root`)

Comment: Technically, you shouldn't be connecting to an external service on the FXAT from the controller.  As soon as you start putting in the logic to handle the connection on a background thread you'll realize that this linear approach  of "connect then display" is not such a good idea.  Anyways, launch your screen with it disconnected, then create Dialog to get the connection details and call its showAndWait().  Then connect using Task on a Background thread and handle the screen updates for connected in its onSucceeded() method.

Comment: This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73528614/230513) illustrates the typical life cycle.

Comment: Take a look at this [Task based splash screen startup](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2305098).  You could modify it to collect user input rather than monitor progess, and have the Task perform your connection as suggested by DaveB. [A similar example](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1588531).